# Something is wrong here in this code please suggest

Tags: c#, sql-server, types

I get this error:

> Input string was not in correct format.

What is wrong in this code?

```
string tot = textBox10.Text;
decimal itot = Int64.Parse(tot);

string qry = "insert into sale (total) values (" + itot + ") ";

SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(qry, con);

int i = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (i >= 1)
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted successfully");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Not done");
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. There is very little code and you don't even mention what language you're programming this in. Please update with details.

Comment: this is a c# coding. i want to parse decimal value from textbox and want to store in Sql table but it shows input string is not in currect format

Comment: Show how you have defined textBox10 as well

Comment: First problem: you're constructing your SQL dynamically. If it *did* work, it would be vulnerable to SQL injection. I would very, very strongly advise you to use parameterized SQL *immediately*. Next, why are you using `Int64.Parse` but assigning the value to a `decimal`? Is it intended to be an integer or not?

Comment: (It sounds like you want to use `decimal.Parse`. But you should **definitely** still fix the SQL Injection Attack vulnerability.)

Answer (score 0):

The only line of code there that would throw that error is your Int64.Parse. It's straight forward and telling you the input string from the textbox is not a number. So if your string has spaces, periods and anything at all except the numbers 0 to 9 or a minus sign then it isn't an integer.

You are likely typing something like 9.4 and want a float or double or decimal.Parse.

I would also recommend doing TryParse not Parse if there is no assurance the input is the correct format